# How to add +1 day to the "To Date" if "From Day" is Sunday?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

> shipout_day_from = 2
>
> shipout_day_to   = 3

If shipout_day_from is Sunday then add +1 day to shipout_day_from & shipout_day_to

If shipout_day_to is Sunday then add +1 day to shipout_day_to. (shipout_day_from wont add +1 day)

```
<div class="shipout">
<p id="postage">Postage: <span id="postage-msg">FREE (UK MAINLAND)</span></p>
<span id="shipout-title"></span><span id="shipout-date"></span>
<script>
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
  locale = "en-us";
  dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
  var curr_date = dat.getDate();
//Changes Start
  var day = dat.getDay();
  if(dat.toLocaleString(locale, { weekday: "long" }) == 'Sunday'){
    curr_date = curr_date + 1;
    day = day + 1;
  }
//Changes End
  var s=["th","st","nd","rd"];
  v= curr_date %100;

  var curr_month = dat.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" });
  return curr_date + (s[(v-20)%10]||s[v]||s[0]) + " " + curr_month + " " + "(" + ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'][day] +")";
}

var dat = new Date();

document.getElementById("shipout-title").innerHTML = "Estimated Delivery: "
document.getElementById("shipout-date").innerHTML =  dat.addDays(<?php echo $_product->getData('shipout_day_from');?>) + " - " + dat.addDays(<?php echo $_product->getData('shipout_day_to')

</script>
</div>
```

As of current Script the Output will be `Estimated Delivery: 25th March (Sat) - 27th March (Mon)` If today is 23rd March Thursday. (Adding +1 day to the TO DATE successfully).

But

As of current Script the Output will be `Estimated Delivery: 27th March (Mon) - 27th March (Mon)` If today is 24th March Friday. (Adding +1 day to the From Date but the TO DATE remains same.)

I need the output like `Estimated Delivery: 27th March (Mon) - 28th March (Tue)` If today is 24th March Friday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINALLY!! check out below code.

```
<div class="shipout">
<p id="postage">Postage: <span id="postage-msg">FREE (UK MAINLAND)</span></p>
<span id="shipout-title"></span><span id="shipout-date"></span>
<script>
var flag = false;;
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  if(flag == true){
    days = days + 1;
    flag = false;
  }
  var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
  locale = "en-us";
  dat.setDate(24 + days);
  var curr_date = dat.getDate();

//Changes Start
  var day = dat.getDay();
  if(dat.toLocaleString(locale, { weekday: "long" }) == 'Sunday'){
    curr_date = dat.getDate() + 1;
    day = day + 1;
    flag = true;
  }

//Changes End
  var s=["th","st","nd","rd"];
  v= curr_date %100;

  var curr_month = dat.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" });
  return curr_date + (s[(v-20)%10]||s[v]||s[0]) + " " + curr_month + " " + "(" + ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'][day] +")";
}

var dat = new Date();

document.getElementById("shipout-title").innerHTML = "Estimated Delivery: "
document.getElementById("shipout-date").innerHTML =  dat.addDays(2) + " - " + dat.addDays(3)

</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Great... It works

Comment: Plz update the other question too... I will mark as answer there too

Comment: your welcome....I updated the another answer too